# How to represent an entangle state on Bloch Sphere

Tags: bloch-sphere

[image]

If states are not entangle, both bloch sphere represent the state of qubit but if they are entangle, why bloch sphere show nothing??

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.01699

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce the error, this code is perfectly working for me. For more you can check [docs](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.visualization.plot_bloch_multivector.html) or can also try  other `visualisation plots` like `plot_state_qsphere(outputstate)`

[image: Bloch sphere representation of the bell state.]